# AppExchange change logo and description after publication

Tags: appexchange, package

It's possible to change the Logo, description ... in appExchange listing without submitting another version of the package?
I tried to figure out from the documentation but I have not found the answer.

Comment: Have you tried logging into your APO and editing the listing? I only have a private listing, but it does appear to provide the means to edit the logo and description. https://appexchange.salesforce.com/resource/1352496302000/help/Content/appexchange_publish_listings_basic.htm https://appexchange.salesforce.com/resource/1352496302000/help/Content/appexchange_publish_listings_upload_content.htm

Comment: Yes I know that is possible to edit listing but I wonder if is also possible to edit it also when the app is submitted. I've read this doc https://na1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_appexchange_publish_guide.pdf but it's not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. We have changed the description, logo etc while we had submitted for review and after it was review had been passed. I dont know if its documented somewhere but we were able to change it.